# When an electron moves in the valence band, does it need energy?

Tags: electricity, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am wondering what actually happens when an electron moves in the valence band. As I understand an electron needs energy to free itself from an atom. Is it so that the electron gets energy to free itself from the atom, then moves to a new atom, and the loses the energy when it recombines with the new atom? If so, how does it initially get the energy?

Comment: It can be supplied via electrical excitation (run a current through semiconductor) or by absorbing a photon for example.

Comment: @DakkVader Thank you! So it is indeed so that when an electron moves in the valence band in a semi conductor, each time it moves it must "leave the valence band" to move to a new atom, and then fall down in the valence band in a new atom?

Comment: Both conduction and valence bands are states that extend across the crystal - electrons and holes are not tied to specific atoms. So, ignore the atoms and only consider the electrons and holes as 'free' (well, not free, but they have a whole band to play in without needing any help).

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you!, so we can not say that when a hole move in the valence band, a covalent bond is first broken and then another covalent bond is formed?

Comment: No, not at all. The valence band also extends throughout the crystal and is not associated with any specific atoms.

Comment: @JonCuster please turn your two commands in a single simple answer as this seems to me the right answer to OP. It will also fix the unwanted diatribe I've initiated trying to address this point.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355197/what-would-an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-e-k-diagram/355840#355840 may provide some background on electronic states in crystals.

Answer (score 1):

First consider a semiconductor. Electrons in the full valence band do not move . Only if one or more electrons are missing, that is, reside in the conduction band, the remaining ones can move. It is convenient to describe this as **hole** conduction. The conduction electron can also move until it recombines with a hole.

Indeed it takes energy to excite an electron from the valence to the conduction band, at least the **band gap** energy. This energy can be thermal. At room temperature there will always be a few electrons and holes around causing **intrinsic conductivity**. Optical excitation is also possible, as happens in solar cells. Electron-hole recombination can also be thermal or radiative, as in LEDs. Semiconductors are usually doped with impurity atoms causing them to have permanent conduction electrons or holes.

In metals it does not take energy to move, or rather, to activate an electron.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am wondering is in relation to your first paragraph. When we have hole conduction, do we then need to excite the electron to move? When a hole moves does the corresponding electron first get excited, then move, and then fall down to the valence band again?

Comment: @user394334 No energy is needed as the total energy is independent of where the hole is located.

Comment: Isn't that something moving need energy to be accelerated? I am afraid your answer is not to the question, as for I takes "moves" as current.

Comment: @Alchimsta If you have a question yourself feel free to ask it.

Comment: @my2cts I see, thank you.

Comment: @my2cts that is a strange comment. Can I say that that the OP question might ask for something else? OP can be even lead astray for all that I know. What had to do the presence of holes or free electrons with their moving? Either the OP means motion as current, that needs energy ; or promotion of electrons into a level /band, and that needs energy too. When you do not need energy to even have carriers, the only concept of "moving" is that of current.

Comment: @Alchimista I don't see a connection between your comments and the question, hence my comment.

Comment: Now I am a little confused here. I will repeat my question if that makes it clearer: When an we have "hole conduction" in the p type in a semi conductor(I am not looking at the depletion layer, but the rest of the p type), when the holes then move the corresponding electron moves, and do we have to "break the covalent bond" these electrons are in, and then form new covalent bonds as the electron(hole) moves? If so, where do we get the energy to break the original covalent bond?

Comment: @user394334 That is indeed the question I answered. If you like, you get the energy to break one bond from reconnecting the other. You always have one broken bond of you have one valence hole.

Comment: @my2cts Ok, thanks.

Comment: @user394334 your description sounds like there is hopping. While one can account for your picture and say that what is spent in a site is recovered from another one, that is not the right picture. The band extends in the material. Similar in metals. There is no a shift of bonds. The free electrons are the bond.

Comment: @Alchimista "The band extends in the material" A band is nothing but an E-k relation for electrons in a crystal. What you probably mean is that the electrons reside in crystal orbitals. Note that for a full band, the Slater determinant of doubly occupied orbitals can be written in terms of localised, Wannier, orbitals and delocalised, crystal, orbitals. These are mathematically identical. That does not mean that there are no covalent bonds in a semiconductor like Si.

Comment: @my2cts don't overshot. Of course there a covalent bonds in a Sil crystal. But those define the lattice and are not the holes / or the electrons. Then there might be a hopping type of description. In that case the energy needed to leave the localized orbitals would be furnished by occupying another one. In that case conductivity should be at least thermally assisted.

Comment: @Alchimista You overshot yourself by bringing up hopping. Why? There is no hopping in a crystalline semiconductor at room temperature. Nor in a normal metal. Are you talking about very poor conductors of amorphous semiconductors? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-range_hopping
And what do you mean that "covalent bonds" "are not the holes / or the electrons" ? Covalent bonds are commonly and reasonably thought of as doubly occupied hybridized atomic orbitals. No electrons no bonds I would say.

Comment: @my2cts :( I was tolerant to the picture given. Do not reverse my comments.

Comment: @Alchimista I was also being tolerant so far. Your comments are besides the point here and create confusion. Please submit your own answer and see what happens in the comment section there.

Comment: @my2cts I've spoken of hopping because it seems the picture that OP had in mind. And your answer did not account for that. But I see that meantime s/he likely got a clearer picture, at least judging from the comments belonging to the original question. And I did not say that what you have wrote is wrong. Let me repeat: I took the question to be about the motion of carriers within the lattice and not about the carriers existence. Perhaps I should have commented to OP asking to make it clearer.

Comment: @my2cts While the total energy remains the same, such that no net energy transfer from the environment is needed for valence electrons to move, will some 'activation energy' not be needed for the covalent bond to break? I visualised this as electrons temporarily jumping to the conduction band, moving (such that the hole moves) to another location and dropping back down. The net energy transfer is still zero, but some sort of activation energy is required. Is this a wrong thought process?

Comment: @vvidyan No electron is activated from valence to conduction. The electron is just moving from one bond to the next.

Comment: @my2cts So just to be clear, electrons CAN move between atoms to get into another bond while being in the valence band? I was of the (perhaps wrong) opinion that an electron could only move if it was in the conduction band, even if it was to go to another bond.

Comment: @VVidyan This is not electron but hole conduction.

Answer (score 0):

Electron travel as waves across the lattice in semiconductors. This is a quantum mechanical effect and to all purposes the image of the electron being stuck and one atom and jumping out is not correct.

When the electron is in an atom it has an amplitude to leak to neighbouring atoms. The fact that amplitudes are complex numbers do place a key role in this description and when you model the system this way, the result is that electrons travel like wavelet.

For more details see https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_13.html

Answer (score 0):

A band is an (allowed) energy state within which an electron can exist. As long as it remains within the valence band, it absorbs and emmits no energy. Energy is absorbed or emitted when there is transition between states. Therefore, to knock an electron off the valence band to a higher one (conduction band) energy must supplied to the electron.